# Adding values to existing node of xml in sql

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and my stored procedure takes a structured xml parameter with multiple levels like this.

```
DECLARE @XML_Account XML=
<Accounts>
    <Account>
        <NameID></NameID>
        <AID></AID>
        <TransactionTime></TransactionTime>
        <TransactionEndTime></TransactionEndTime>
        <TrasactionName></TrasactionName>
        <Purchases>
            <Purchase>
                <Name></Name>
                <Qty></Qty>
                <Cost></Cost>
                <Tax1></Tax1>
                <Tax2></Tax2>
                <Tax3></Tax3>
                <Tax4></Tax4>
            </Purchase>
           <Purchase>
                <Name></Name>
                <Qty></Qty>
                <Cost></Cost>
                <Tax1></Tax1>
                <Tax2></Tax2>
                <Tax3></Tax3>
                <Tax4></Tax4>
            </Purchase>
        </Purchases>
        <Error></Error>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

now here i want to add values to error node like `<Error>please check error</Error>`
and return the xml parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remove empty node (becase it fails replacement):

```
SET @XML_Account.modify('delete (Accounts/Account/Error)[1]')
```

Then, add your error:

```
SET @XML_Account.modify('insert <Error>please check error</Error> as last into (Accounts/Account)[1]')
```

The easiest way to set error in many nodes to use REPLACE:

```
SET @XML_Account = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @XML_Account), N'<Error/>',N'<Error>please check error</Error>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,above solution is perfectly working for single <Account> not its not giving output if node repeat

Comment: @IrfanShaikh if node repeat, in with one do you want to set error?

Comment: here node <Account> can be repeated with its childs nodes n number of time i want set error for each <Error> node in the <Account> node.